# Deploying application developed using C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, compilation, visual-studio-2010

I have an application that uses `wxWidgets` as a the UI framework and compiled using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 machine. I am linking `wxWidgets` statically. My application also uses a C dll for processing.

Now I am trying to run this application on another freshly installed machine (Win7). This doesn't have a developer environment setup. I have copied the application's executable file, supporting dll and other supporting text files to this machine.

When the application starts, it gave the following message.

`The program failed to start because MSVCR100d.DLL is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem`.

I figured that my C library was using debug version and compiling that in `Release` mode solved the issue. But it still asks for `MSVCR100.dll`. I think the way to workaround is installing the VC++ redistributable package. But not sure that is the best approach.

Here are my questions.

1. How do you normally deploy the application? Do you provide the VC++ redistributable package too?
2. I am compiling this on a 64bit machine and testing on a 32 bit. Is this OK? Or do I need to compile separately for 32 bit?
3. Can I statically link against the run time library? So that I can just ship my DLLs and other files.
4. What are the other common things that I should be aware of when building executable which will run on many machines?

Following are some of my settings which may be relevant.

```
General : 
    Use of MFC : Use standard windows libraries
    Use of ATL : Not using

C/C++ :
    Runtime library : Multi-threaded(/MT)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trying to use a debug only DLL on a machine that doesn't have it.

Your problem arises from the fact that msvcr100d.dll is a debug only dll indicated by the trailing d.

Thus you are NOT using /MT you are actually using /MDd.  If you used /MT then it would nto try and load that DLL ...

So in answer to your questions:

1. I prefer to statically link against the run-time.
2. Thats really not a problem.  Just don't try and run a 64-bit compiled binary on a 32-bit OS.
3. Yes.
4. Beware of your minimum specification.  ie Don't use SSE4 if you need to support a Pentium 3 ... etc.

Comment: thank you. I have also read about avoiding the MS compiler altogether and use GCC on MinGW. Do you have any opinion on that?

Comment: @Appu: The MSVC compiler is pretty sweet. There's little/no reason to change.

Comment: @Appu: I agree with DeadMG.  Its worth noting, if you take the GCC, train then you will find that Visual Studio makes your life many times easier.  I'll happily handle either but I'd FAR rather just handle Developer Studio :)

Comment: Thanks. But my issue is not fully solved. How can I statically link the run time?

Comment: @Appu: By using the /MT switch (Project Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Runtime library set to "Multi-threaded").  That statically links against the runtime.  I know you say you are already doing this but if it is trying to use the DLL you obviously aren't ... make sure you are doing this for debug (Though debug would be using /MTd) AND release (ie using /MT).

Comment: Ok. I am using `wxWidgets` libraries also. Sometimes that may be using a different linkage. I will take a look at that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Appu:  wxWidgets can be used with statically or dynamically linked CRT AFAICR ...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the same question as the second hit when I googled "will x86 exe work on x64"; it doesn't answer everything, but it has a few answers.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/5ad0ff2c-558c-43ba-a59d-9cd0a0785103

You can probably find more similar information if you look beyond the second one, and if you query for a few other things.

As for the VC++ runtime stuff, I avoid MS's C++ version like the plague myself and so have no experience with it, but still, I thought all modern Windows computers were supposed to have the necessary runtime components of all their stuff (VC++, .NET, etc) already included.

Comment: How can you avoid MS's version of the runtime when programming in C and/or C++ for Windows?

Comment: I don't develop for only Windows. And besides, just because you develop something for windows that does not mean that you need the VC++ runtime; x86 instructions don't care what OS is running them. And is the VC++ runtime synonymous with Windows system libraries? Just because I include windows.h and use Sleep(), does that need VC++ runtime? If I then use WinAPI to set up a GUI window, does that need VC++? I would think not, but MS does integrate some things into OS/shell operations that they probably shouldn't, so maybe VC++ runtime really is synonymous with Windows system calls.

Comment: Comments are too short; normally I don't like to do this, but I feel it's beneficial to bleed into a second one since I ran out of chars on the first. Obviously, if you use VC++ to make the application, it probably requires their runtime no matter what. I also don't use VC++ even when developing in C++ for Windows. I use MinGW. But again, this question is important, and probably deserves its own question post: what exactly is in the VC++ runtime that the applications require? Is it required for any Windows-specific things (WinAPI f.ex. Sleep() CreateWindow() etc.), or is it just support?

Comment: @Loduqijk: The VC++ runtime is the CRT, and some C++ features like exceptions, RTTI, dynamic_cast, that sort of thing. Any Windows app that didn't write their own CRT from scratch (or have it done by the compiler vendor, I guess) uses the VC++ runtime. WinAPI and the VC++ runtime are totally independent things- you don't need VC++ to call Sleep(). Windows 7 was released before MSVC10. It likely comes with MSVC9 runtimes. I personally always statically link.

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes, it is necessary to provide VC++ redistributable package. The best way is to make a setup package using Visual Studio Setaul and Deployment project.
2. It's OK if you compile 32 bits executable.
3. I don't recommend this, such huge executables don't look professional.

Comment: TBH they don't end up that huge.  The link stripper removes a lot of the chafe.  It makes for a MUCH smaller re-dist than having to also send people the vcredist installer package.

Comment: I can't remember the last time I considered a "huge" executable to be unprofessional. What a minute, I can't recall the last time I checked an executable's file size...